# Python writes questions instead of string to file

Tags: python, writetofile

I want to write data from API to file, but i get weird characters written to file instead of string

```
import requests
end_url = url `+ "?key=" + api_key + "&lang=en-ru" + "&text=" + "Hello 
world"
response = requests.get(end_url)   
str = response.json()["text"][0]   
print(type(str)) # class 'str'   
print(str) # string that i want to write to file   
file = open("translate.txt", 'r+')   
file.write(str)
```

It should write string which i get from API to file, but it writes this:
�����`

Comment: Try `file = open("translate.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: `print(str)` A sample of it?

Comment: may be you are receiving bytes , what is the api you are using ?

Comment: pistol2myhead's comment answered my question, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try **encoding** flag in open function

```
import requests

end_url = url `+ "?key=" + api_key + "&lang=en-ru" + "&text=" + "Hello world"

response = requests.get(end_url)   
str = response.json()["text"][0]   

print(type(str)) # class 'str'   
print(str) # string that i want to write to file   

file = open("translate.txt", 'r+', encoding='utf-8')   
file.write(str)
```

Basically encoding is the way for computer to store text in files

If you want to know more about [UTF-8](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)